# model goes to nan loss with data modification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have an imbalanced dataset over which I'm doing binary classification. This model works. However, if I approximately balance the dataset (by deleting all rows with probability `p` where `p` is the frequency of the label - example below) and try to train the model, the loss becomes nan within the first epoch. Loss hovers around approximately 7.5 before becoming nan so I don't think it's the loss exploding.

Any ideas why?

```
import random
l = list()
for i,r in df.iterrows(),:
    p = df.groupby('label').count().col1[r['label']]/len(df.index)
    if random.random() > p:
        l.append(r)
l = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Comment: Please provide more information on the type of data/features, network, and loss you are using. It would be best to provide (minimal) code to reproduce the error.

One side note: Shouldn't you delete the rows with probability `p` where `p` is the frequency of the same label, in order to balance the classes? Anyway, I would suggest rather to duplicate instances of the minority class, unless you have a very large amount of data.

Comment: @Max - Sorry, I misspoke. Yes, I delete with same frequency. I have enough data. I am just equalizing the data to view another issue in the model